# Which type of Finger Print reader better for .Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fingerprint

I want to implement fingerprint reader device for my school management Application for attendance managing.Which is done on .Net c# 4.6 version. which device is best for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [here](https://www.suprema-id.com/en/contents/detail.php?code=010301) if you need USB fingerprint reader. Some model is supporting RF Cards(EM, Mifare, iClass, ...)

Or, check [here](http://sfm.supremainc.com/) if you need modules to implement a reader device(or appliance).